# Elasticsearch cluster cannot discover nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, yaml, elasticsearch-7

I'm trying to setup a 2 node cluster. But it seems like the nodes cannot discover each other.

Node 1 yaml file

```
cluster.name: es-cluster
node.name: es-node-a
path.data: /my/path/data/elasticsearch
path.logs: /my/path/log/elasticsearch
network.host: xx.xxx.xxx.xx
discovery.seed_hosts:
        - yy.yyy.yyy.yy
cluster.initial_master_nodes:
        - es-node-a
        - es-node-b
```

Node 2 yaml file

```
cluster.name: es-cluster
node.name: es-node-b
path.data: /my/path/data/elasticsearch
path.logs: /my/path/log/elasticsearch
network.host: yy.yyy.yyy.yy
discovery.seed_hosts:
        - xx.xxx.xxx.xx
cluster.initial_master_nodes:
        - es-node-a
        - es-node-b
```

Is something wrong with my configuration?

Comment: What do you have in the logs? Update your question with the log messages. Also, put both nodes in  the `discovery.seed_hosts` configuration. But with 2 nodes I would recommend to choose one of them to be the master and set the other to be non-master eligible, in a 2 node cluster there is no resilience, you can't afford to lose a node, so it is easier to have just one master eligible.

Answer (score 0):

Set both discovery.seed_hosts to the same host.

I agree with @leandrojmp, in a 2-node cluster setup, you can only choose 1 node to be the fixed master node permanently. Read [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/high-availability-cluster-small-clusters.html).